# The procedure Entry point can not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, command-line, dynamic-library

I have my c++ program which contains tbe following code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void calculateResults(int, int, int, int);

int main() {
  cout << "Plese insert four integers: \n";
  int ar1,par1,ar2,par2;
  cin >> ar1 >> par1 >> ar2 >> par2;
  if(par1 == 0 || par2 ==0) {
    error("O paronomasths den mporei na einai 0!\n");
  } else {
    calculateResults(ar1,par1,ar2,par2);
  }
  return 0;
}

void calculateResults(int ar1,int par1,int ar2,int par2) {
  class Negative_Sqrt_Input {};
  ar1 *= par2;
  ar2 *= par1;
  double resAr = ar1 - ar2;
  double resPar = par1*par2;
  if(resAr < 0 || resPar < 0) {
    throw Negative_Sqrt_Input();
  } else {
    double sqrtResAr = sqrt(resAr);
    double sqrtResPar = sqrt(resPar);
    cout << sqrtResAr << "/" << sqrtResPar;
  }
}
```

and i get the following error: **The procedure entry point _ZNSt13runtime_errorC1ERKNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEE could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\Steli\Desktop\fractions_ex1.exe**

I've searched through various stack posts but had no luck finding the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: The error means your program has somehow incorrectly static linked to the `std::runtime_error` constructor that takes a `std::string` as input as if it were an imported DLL function, and is looking for that "function" to be exported by the EXE itself instead of a separate DLL. Either you have a buggy STL library, or you didn't setup your project correctly.

Comment: You probably copied Soustrup's library from somewhere.  It has to be rebuilt to match the runtime library installed on your machine.

Comment: @HansPassant yes it was given to us by our University. Should i post it?

Comment: No.  Talk to the professor or an assistant about it, they need to provide you with a better library.